# How to copy my project folders and subfolders except contents (but PDF's must be included)

Tags: pdf, directory, copy, structure, copy-paste

I'm a machine designer and I have a lots of project folders. I must copy my folders to public account, but public account area is limited. I must copy all folder structure include only pdf files. Other files must be except this. I.e. all folders and subfolders must be included and just pdf files.

If there is no pdf in that file, it should just copy the empty folder.
I can use only command prompt, I have no idea how I can with coding. Sorry for my English..

I tried search on google and I found this:
https://itigic.com/tr/use-xcopy-to-copy-a-folder-structure-in-windows/
"Xcopy" can be copy all folder structure but it can't copy pdf files.

I need only pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Xcopy, Copies files and directory trees.

```
XCOPY source [destination] [/A | /M] [/D[:date]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z] [/B] [/J]
                           [/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...] [/COMPRESS]
```

It can seem daunting to a first-time user

*" I must copy my folders to public account "*
so first where in Public
[image]

Let us ASSUME "c:\users\PUBLIC\Public Documents" (**WARNING note public is 2 times**)

Make sure we will not destroy by overwrite other folders
[image]

**WARNING** Public Documents is a symbolic link thus that is **NOT it's true** folder name,
we must **NOT have 2 Public, only 1** for xcopy, here I ask for a new folder called **PDFs**

> Öte yandan /E, Xcopy'ye şunları da eklemesini söyler: alt klasörler tüm yapıyı kullanmak için boş olan, burada ilgilendiğimiz şey bu.

Navigate to the master folder you want to copy from
type cmd.exe in the address bar and press enter **check cmd is showing that working folder>**
[image]

and you want only all *.pdf  and /E empty folders **FROM THE CURRENT WORKING FOLDER**. So from that working folder run xcopy, which should ask about the need for a new target.

`xcopy *.pdf "c:\users\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\PDFs" /E`

```
Does C:\users\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\PDFs specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? d

C:2022-11-16ExistingCustomerSRFINAL.pdf
C:2022-11-16NewBusinessSRFINAL.pdf
C:adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf
....
many files and folders
...
C:tiff\TIFF6.pdf
C:tiff\TIFFphotoshop.pdf
C:tiff\TIFFPM6.pdf
```

[image]
[image]